# Windows - A different way to Search files by extension

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-vista, search

I'd like to search all files that are different from a specific extension. So, if I search files by using the string ***.doc** I'd like to see every files that are not **.doc**.

I also would like to hidden the sub-folders in the result display by using that search (but the search must of course search into sub-folders) :)

Is it possible this on Windows Vista/7?

**SOLUTION**

Finded the solution by using this string **NOT *.doc AND NOT tipologia:=cartella**

This for the italian version. English should be similar, somethings like **NOT *.doc AND NOT kind:=folder**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd search for "NOT *.doc" (without quotes)

From [here](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/desktopsearch/choose/tipsandtricks.mspx)

> NOT will search for all files not containing the search term in question.

The page also notes that operators AND, NOT and OR must be in capital letters, otherwise they will behave as just another search term.

Comment: Nice one! It works. And if I'd like to exclude `*.doc` and `folder`?

Comment: Exclude a specific folder from the search? Not sure I'm afraid.  Are you wanting to search the whole machine for not doc files? Or just a specific area? If you ALWAYS wanted to exclude a specific folder, I guess you could exclude it from the search index (Indexing options in Control Panel) but I don't think you'd be able to do it on a one off basis. Happy to be proven wrong though!

Comment: Example : I have a main Folder with : 10 Subfolder, 4 mp3 files, 3 jpg files and 3 doc! I'll like to see all files that aren't doc (so only the mp3 and the jpg ones) on the main Folder. I'd like to do somethings like `-*.doc` and a string that tell the search "don't show the folder". Is it more clear? :)

Comment: It is, and as you said above, using the combination should do it. :)

Answer (score 1):

See [**Set Windows Search to not include sub-folders when typing in the search box**](http://maximumpcguides.com/windows-7/set-windows-search-to-not-include-subfolders-when-typing-in-search-box/).

The first option in "How to search" could thus be disabled:

[image]

---

A very quick light-weight search engine that allows you to search any way is [Search Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/).

1. `C:\Path\To\Location\ !.doc`
2. Sort by path, the files not in the sub-folders are listed first.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I've explain my problem in a bad way! I want that search is doing in the subfolder, but I want that they are not be displayed:)

Comment: Ah, doesn't matter, I've got reputation for the effort. Yes, it's indeed with `kind`. I like a search on `kind:*` which gives all indexed items... :-)